# python type hinting for class and children in composition class

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to basically do this:

```
@dataclass
class A:
    pass

@dataclass
class B(A):
   pass

@dataclass
class container:
   stuff: List[A OR B OR any future defined child class]
```

The only way I've found by looking around here and on the PEP484 page seems to look something like this...except it doesn't work

```
thing_co = TypeVar('thing_co', covariant=True)
class ListOfAOrLower(List[thing_co ]):
    pass

@dataclass
class container:
   stuff: ListOfAOrLower
```

When I try to create my container (ie "container([B()])"), pylance in vscode says the types are not compatible. When I try to say "stuff" is a List[thing_co], pylance reports "TypeVar "thing_co" has no meaning in this context".

I feel like what I'm trying to do is stupidly simple, and yet I cannot make the type checker accept this pretty standard formulation. Can anyone suggest how to bend the type checker to my will? Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why `stuff: List[A]` isn't good enough? As far as I remember, type assertions are covariant by default, so a type checker should accept any subclass of `A`. You also might want to use `mypy` to assert correctness, maybe it's a bug in pylance.

Comment: It may be a bug, thats a good point. I'll see if anything has been reported. I use pylance because it is like 1000x better on everything else in my experience.

List[A] definitely didn't work, thats what I assumed would be OK and it fussed.

Edit: it may be an interaction with how the dataclass decorator works. Maybe I'll just create that class manually.

Comment: A list is *invariant* because it can be both written to and read from. It doesn't make sense for a List to contain "A or child classes", and if you force it to this can introduce subtle bugs. Did you intend to make ``container`` generic over *some specific* subclass of ``A``?

Comment: So it does seem to have been the dataclass issue. Just made it a dataclass with a user-defined init function and the type hints were accepted.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't fully understand. To perhaps make this simpler, I have a stupidly simple excel file I'm loading so I don't have to bother making a real UI for this application, and I have basically 2 file formats with slight differences. Version A has columns X, Y, Z. Version B has W,X,Y,Z. So I want to have a generic function to load that, but the actual consumer knows if its expecting A or B data. I just want the loader to not know. Basically i want to not copy-paste the same 10 lines of openpyxl code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for me was with pylance interacting with the dataclass decorator. It was resolved by specifying my own init function.